# How to include header File in HTML

Tags: html, web, import

I have the following file structure
I am trying to take the header.html from the _includes directory, and import it into the index.html file so that the text from it shows up in the main file(index.html)

I have already tried this `{% include header.html %}` but all that shows up is `{% include header.html %}` instead of the text that is in header.html

Comment: You can't do that in pure HTML. The  {% include header.html %} looks like a template engine code, maybe something from Jekyll (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/)?

Comment: Based on what should `{% include ... %}` even work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a Jekyll site based on your screenshot (the _config.yml and the {% include header.html %} both matches Jekyll). Maybe check out https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `w3-include-html` from [w3.js](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/default.asp)

Example:

`<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>`

[HTML Include](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)